# Mocha JS & Javascript libraries - What is this library?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I just started learning Mocha and I was going through its document at https://mochajs.org/#hooks

There was one of example and it is using something like:
    var db = new Connection
I can understand what it does... but is it vanilla javascript?? Or some db related javascript library?

I was curious the name of this library (so I can study later). Thank you.

```
describe('Connection', function() {
  var db = new Connection,
  tobi = new User('tobi'),
  loki = new User('loki'),
  jane = new User('jane');

  beforeEach(function(done) {
    db.clear(function(err) {
      if (err) return done(err);
      db.save([tobi, loki, jane], done);
    });
  });

  describe('#find()', function() {
    it('respond with matching records', function(done) {
      db.find({type: 'User'}, function(err, res) {
        if (err) return done(err);
        res.should.have.length(3);
        done();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I think that's just a generic example, the specific API will depend on the DB and library you're using.

Comment: Yup that's not a library, just an example like `User` in `new User('tobi')` (which is an awesome name by the way)

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you so much!

Comment: @Geotob Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two people above answered my question. It was just a generic example.